# Prevent parent scroll on absolute child div

Tags: html, css

How can I get my child div to overlay the parent but not let the parent scroll? My child div needs to be like a popup that will fill the `viewport` and scroll the content but shouldn't be able to scroll anything passed it's `viewport`. Once dismissed it can scroll the parent as is. I'm trying to find a pure CSS fix.

```
<div id="main">
<div>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Enough to cause an overflow/td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="top-nav">
    </div>
    <div class="content-nav">
        <div>
            <li>This is my overlay content</li>
            <li>This is my overlay content</li>
            <li>This is my overlay content</li>             
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz7tsxyd/)

Comment: 1. Don't use tables for something like this 2. If the parent isn't taking up all of the screen and is positioned then the child cannot take up the full screen 3. Your question is unclear, I have no idea what you *actually* want

Comment: I believe he wants the grey container to completely cover the `content` container, thus removing the outer scrollbar. But using only CSS to accomplish this. Additionally, I'd say using tables are fine for mocking up a quick example of something... but you may want to wrap your `<li>`s in a `<ul>` :)